# Firebug Error (missing ) after argument list)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am receiving an error in firebug on a site I have literally been trying to work the kinks out of for a year. If someone could take a look at the code and tell me where I'm going wrong, I would appreciate it. Here is the exact error I am getting:

missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error] $("#guts").load(url, {}, function(){ $('a.ceebox').ceebox(); });

My script/code is below.

Thank you in advance...

```
$(function() {

    var newHash      = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
        baseHeight   = 0,
        $el;

    $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
    baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash) {
            $mainContent
                .find("#guts")
                .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function()
        $("#guts").load(url, {}, function(){ $('a.ceebox').ceebox(); });

 {
                        $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                            $pageWrap.animate({
                                height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                            });
                        });
                        $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                        $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                    });
                });
        };

    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to really help with jQuery and doesn't seem a useful recommendation in this case, but maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Curly bracket misplaced. You had:

```
...
$mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function()
        $("#guts").load(url, {}, function(){ $('a.ceebox').ceebox(); });

 {
...
```

Should be

```
...
$mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
        $("#guts").load(url, {}, function(){ $('a.ceebox').ceebox(); });
...
```

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
$("#guts").load(url, {}, function(){ $('a.ceebox').ceebox(); });
```

is in a wrong place. the `function()` definition in the line above has no opening `{`. It comes right after the mentioned line.

this may a working code but I don't know if the mentioned line is in the right place

```
$(function() {

    var newHash = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap = $("#page-wrap"),
        baseHeight = 0,
        $el;

    $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
    baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash) {
            $mainContent.find("#guts").fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $("#guts").load(url, {}, function() {
                        $('a.ceebox').ceebox();
                    });
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href=" + newHash + "]").addClass("current");
                });
            });
        }

    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

And you should follow Matt Ball's comment.

Comment: This is only your code, but without syntax errors. So bear with me, that I can't assume, what your entire script should do at all. It was a grammar correction of your 'Mandarin Chinese' ;-)

Comment: Here is the problem that I am having. I had coded this site and tried to implement a dynamic content refresh without a page reload. Unfortunately, Ceebox (the modal popup that I was using) would cease to function after the ajax load. So, I have tried and tried to get someone to help me work it out and could never figure it out. This morning, I found a post (similar) that recommended adding the following line:

$("#guts").load(url, {}, function(){ $('a.ceebox').ceebox(); });

Comment: The truth is though, I have no idea how to implement that concept. Here is the original code...

Could you help me understand where exactly I would add that line in the initial code? Cause, to be honest...I don't even know what that line does. I just know that after I added it...after a year of tinkering...the modal box worked after a dynamic content refresh (like it was supposed to). :)

Comment: It isn't that easy. `$("#guts").load(url, {}, function(){ $('a.ceebox').ceebox(); });` uses the variable `url` which is not defined in your script. Sorry, but I see no way to help you any further here with the information you have given.

Comment: I really am trying to give more information but it keeps cutting me off on the character limit. *lol* I've never used this site before. So, I'm trying to figure out if I'm even posting properly...